# how to resize an image HTML

Tags: php, windows, image, resize

just a little study project i am doing and ive come over a issue with a ".php?" problem.

ill REALLY appreciate anyone who can resolve these problems for me and i really doubt it will be a big job. probably got files around which are annoying and messy... not too sure. ive tried online sources and helps but no luck.

ive provided a link to download the source files and screenshots to show my problem.

[enter image description here][1]
ill really appreciate it being solved.... if possible. with a re-download link :(

Thankyou!!!

Arsheya Kh.

Source Code - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1itUHsLQ6MzMP8cA35AD5qnAm7IDSWFNW?usp=sharing

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kym1u.png < this image is showing my problem.
for example a customer wants a window clicks that> clicks what type of window > and the page with the problem should show the window image thats included in the source code and also resize itself with the customers size.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBSTC.png > this is the final error that i have.
i cannot change the final details.

example of the website is modernwindows.co.uk

Answer (score -1):

Basic thing is you have an option by css

Your html file will contain  Image tag

```
<img class="fake" src="example.png" />
```

And you need to add this code directly to the css file

```
img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
     -moz-transform: scale(0.5); /* FF3.5+ */
      -ms-transform: scale(0.5); /* IE9 */
       -o-transform: scale(0.5); /* Opera 10.5+ */
          transform: scale(0.5);}
```

You need to use transform property...!!

Comment: where would i put this  code sorry as ive only started and have so many random files...

Comment: No luck.... i believe its a issue with my preview commands. to allow the picture to be resized and previewed. however nothing is working not even the video. i have ensured all the images and names are the same but no luck

Comment: You can make a simple html page and try it out..!! If it works in it than surely it might work in your project..!!